# $_SESSION not holding array

Tags: php, html

I used the `$_SESSION` to store the name of the user that logged in but it doesn't store it. I did an `echo var_dump($_SESSION);` and it said `array(0) {}`. Why is the `$_SESSION` not holding the name?

It's on *localhost*, I have put `session_start();` on top of every *.php* file.

### login.inc.php

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
//dehash pass
$hashpwdcheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['password']);
if($hashpwdcheck == false){
header("Location: ../index.php?Login=passwordError".$row);
exit();
}elseif($hashpwdcheck==true){
//login
$_SESSION['id'] = $row["userId"];
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
$_SESSION['pos'] = $row['position'];
header("Location: ../home.php?Login=Success");
exit();
}
}
```

### head.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['name'])){
echo $_SESSION['name'];} else { echo  var_dump($_SESSION); }
?>
```

The result I get is `array(0){}`

Comment: already define `session_start();` ? and make sure your `$row['name']` isn't empty

Comment: Verify with `var_dump(session_id());` that you get the same session on each request. If you get a different session on each request, that will mean that you don't transfer the session id to the server as you should. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the session at the top of the page before assigning values to the session variable. You can do that using`session_start()` function.

Comment: OP have put session_start(); on top of every .php file.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i think my pc was the problem. i rebooted it and it was fixed. i didnt know what happed.